# How to compile GDB for ARM on Ubuntu x64?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, gdb, arm

I have Ubuntu 12.10 x64 on virtual machine, and I need to compile GDB 7.5 for ARM platform.
Can anybody provide me instructions to do this? (I tried variety command line options but no positive results.)

I need an ARM gdbserver and x86/x64 client.

Thank U.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5665800/981380) on SO that discusses a similar issue.

- Download the source code for gdbserver from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)
- Then follow the instructions in the thread linked above.  General instructions will be similar but there'll likely be some changes depending on your platform and build environment as it exists.
- In case it's useful here a [link](http://www.gnuarm.com/pdf/gdb.pdf) to the gdb manual.

The steps above are just a basic guideline.  If you run into any specific issue edit your post with more details about where the build fails.

Good luck!