# Remote debugging using gdb server and client not working

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I am trying to get going remote debugging using gdbserver running on a ARM target running Linux kernel version 2.6.38.8.

On this target I run a gdbserver which is a **32-bit** ELF file, as below:

```
./gdbserver --remote-debug --attach 192.xxx.xxx.2:2345 1600

Attached; pid = 1600
Listening on port 2345
```

The gdb server on starting says:

> This gdbserver was configured as "**arm-none-linux-gnueabi**"

On a Ubuntu (32 bit) machine I run the GDB client which also seems **32 bit**(/usr/bin/gdb) as below to connect to the remote GDB server.
On the GDB prompt I enter as below:

```
(gdb) **target remote 192.xxx.xxx.2:2345**

Remote debugging using 192.xxx.xxx.2:2345

**warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description**
```

Below are errors I see on the GDB prompt of the client:

```
Remote 'g' packet reply is too long: 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
(gdb)
```

After issuing this command, I see below error on target gdbserver:

```
Remote debugging from host 192.xxx.xxx.28

**readchar: Got EOF**

Remote side has terminated connection.  GDBserver will reopen the connection.
```

The client gdb says:

```
This GDB was configured as "**i686-linux-gnu**".
```

Note: Also tried running gdbserver on the target with the `--target-debug` option, but still it did not work, but it spitted more errors on the server upon the client trying to connect. I can put up those errors if it helps.

See the [Errors](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByuMwWMOjsD0MGEzLXEtZWUxMms/view?usp=sharing).

What is the error saying?

What is the mismatch between server, client?

How can I resolve this and get it working?

Comment: I can't test this, but it would probably help to install an ARM-aware gdb on the x86 system. `apt-get install gdb-arm-none-eabi` will install `/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb`, which on my ubuntu 14.04 64-bit system reports `This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi"`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Will check tomorrow and update

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - When i tried to install using apt-get install gdb-arm-none-eabi , got an error saying "Unable to locate package gdb-arm-none-eabi" . What am i missing? How do i install that gdb package?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - I even tried building gdb 7.3 from src to configure for target=arm and it failed. Would it be possible for you to share that gdb binary for arm target you have please?

Comment: Ubuntu I have is 11.10 (32bit) system

Comment: Oh, 11.10 is very old and may not have that package. The gdb binary I have is for 64-bit systems, so that won't help you. I downloaded the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/devel/gdb-arm-none-eabi , so you can try downloading the i386 version there. Note the list of other packages it requires and make sure you have them; look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release for info on getting packages for old Ubuntu releases.

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665800/compiling-gdb-for-remote-debugging), you can use `./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi ` to compile gdb for an ARM target.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - Thanks. Yes , its  soup of a situation. I tried configuring gdb 7.8 with target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi but the subsequent make fails saying "configure error termcap not found"

Comment: IIRC, you'll need to have libncurses5-dev, libexpat1-dev, and (optionally) python-dev installed to compile gdb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63506/discussion-between-goldenmean-and-mark-plotnick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get a GDB server and GDB client which have worked for my 32-bit Ubuntu (client GDB) and ARM Cortex A8 target (GDB server). I got the pre-built binaries from [the Linaro toolchain binaries link](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/trunk/2012.10/+download/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2012.10-20121022_linux.tar.bz2).

These worked perfectly!

I also tried [a later version of the 4.9 toolchain](http://www.linaro.org/downloads/), and it worked as well.